# How to backup Windows 10 Mail accounts

Tags: email

I have a lot of custom domains mails added in my Mail app on Windows 10, and it is a pain to add them at first.

I'd like to know where these accounts are saved in order to copy the file containing this information.
[image]

Comment: You probably want to obfuscate that list or remove the image...

Comment: See this article>>>>https://recoverit.wondershare.com/computer-backup/backup-emails-to-external-storage.html

Comment: @Saaransh Garg thank you for obfuscating the image. I had to override the edit so it was approved instantly rather than requiring more approval votes. Hope you don't mind. :)

Comment: @LPChip, Nope, I don't ^_^

Comment: @spikey_richie Why is that?

Comment: @Moab This article is only about backing up emails right? I'd like to back up all of my accounts connection information (user name, password, host name, protocol, etc.)

Comment: @AlexandreDaubricourt because you basically advertised your e-mail addresses to the world.

Comment: @spikey_richie These emails are all around the web, they are meant for people to contact me

Answer (score 2):

AppData for Window's inbuilt apps and other apps downloaded via Microsoft Store is usually stored in `%appdata%/../local/packages`. Now the Packet name for Windows mail is microsoft.windowscommunicationsapps, So the directory of AppData  is `%appdata%/../local/packages/microsoft.windowscommunicationsapps_8wekyb3d8bbwe`. You can copy all of this data(This is how I prefer it, ensures that your app opens in exact same state as you'd leave it) Or just The LocalState folder, which contains the main data. 
When You'll paste this data back it'll automatically add those mails.

Comment: Thanks! I did not manage to find the specific file (is there is any single one) that stores the accounts config. I'll copy all of the folder as you said